# Response Descriptor with unexpected value for a keyPath

Tags: ios, restkit, restkit-0.20, key-value-coding

I have a response descriptor that maps a response using a keyPath such as  `@"rootKey.subKey"`, where rootKey is a dictionary and subKey is an array. e.g.

```
{rootKey:{subKey:[@"object1", @"object2",...,]}}
```

But some times I get the following response:

```
{rootKey:@""}
```

And my app crashes with an exception that `NSString` isn't key value coding-compliant for the key 'subKey'.

Any ideas how can I handle such situations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I handled it was to create a response descriptor for the top level key, i.e. @"rootKey", instead of @"rootKey.subKey", and created a top level object that only has a single relationship property "subKeys". Then I created a dynamic mapping which based on the representation of the top level objects, either returns a mapping for the subKeys, or nil:

```
RKEntityMapping *responseMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"RootObject" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
[responseMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"subKeys" toKeyPath:@"subKeys" withMapping:subKeysMapping]];

RKDynamicMapping* dynamicMapping = [RKDynamicMapping new];
[dynamicMapping setObjectMappingForRepresentationBlock:^RKObjectMapping *(id representation) {
    if ([representation isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        return responseMapping;
    }
    return nil;
}];

return dynamicMapping;
```

This leads to having an unnecessary top level object (RootObject) but handles the response gracefully when instead of a key-value object, I get a string.

Answer (score 0):

Best option, fix the JSON.

Fallback option, use a [dynamic mapping](http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKDynamicMapping.html) to check what has been received and create a mapping on the fly to handle it.

Comment: I actually tried that, but it seems like the crash still happens even if in such a case I return a 'nil' response mapping to use when no 'subKey' is pressent i.e. root object is string.

Comment: So that's the entire JSON and you only want that one sub key? Fix the response (should return an http status code to indicate no content in this case).

Comment: Any hints on a solution other than fixing the api response? If all fails I might go ahead and make a complex relationship based mapping to be able to detect when expected object isn't there.

Comment: You could look at creating a mapping which creates an error object when the dynamic mapping finds no real content and then handle the error object in the success callback.